# Docker - Import local module on executable Python script

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

First of all, I'm relatively new to Docker, so sorry if my question is dumb or inmediat.

I'm building a multi-container App and I'm having problems displaying one of its services which works fine on local. Here is some of my Docker arquitecture:

**Docker Compose**

```
version: '2'

services:
  dashboard:
    build: demo-dashboard/
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - ES_ENDPOINT_EXTERNAL=http://localhost:9200
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin=ES_ENDPOINT_EXTERNAL
      - http.cors.allow-headers=Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With
      - http.cors.allow-credentials=true
    volumes:
     - ./demo-dashboard:/usr/src/app
    networks:
      - dashboard-network

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.7.0
    environment:
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - http.cors.enabled=true
      - http.cors.allow-origin=http://localhost:8080
      - http.cors.allow-headers=Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With
      - http.cors.allow-credentials=true
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    mem_limit: 1g
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - dashboard-network
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

  orchestrator:
    image: orchestrator-mabsed
    build: orchestrator/
    volumes:
      - './orchestrator/tasks.py:/soneti/tasks.py'
    ports:
     - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      ES_HOST: 'elasticsearch'
    tty: true

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local

networks:
  dashboard-network:
    driver: bridge
```

The service which presents the problem is the orchestrator, whose **Dockerfile** looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.6

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt

COPY tasks.py .
COPY detector/ .
COPY filter/ .
COPY lemmatizer/ .

COPY my_sched.py .
RUN python my_sched.py
```

`my_sched.py` is a scheduler file which runs every 5 minutes and launches a Luigi pipeline contained in `tasks.py` file checking if certain requirements are met. Here is `my_sched.py` file

```
import sched, time
import sys
import subprocess

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def cron():
    s.enter(5*60, 1, cron, [])
    command = '{} -m luigi --local-scheduler --module tasks Main'.format(sys.executable)
    output = subprocess.check_output(command.split(), shell= False)

s.enter(5, 1, cron, [])
s.run()
```

There is a problem as in `tasks.py` file I need to import a component contained in my local folder `filter` and it seems that the Docker container doesn't find it.

`tasks.py` import part looks like this:

```
import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True

# orchestration
import luigi
from luigi.contrib.esindex import CopyToIndex
import datetime

# filter
import os
import csv
import json
from filter.filter import filter_spam

# lemmatizer
from lemmatizer.lemmatizer import lemmatize
from cube.api import Cube

# detection
sys.path.insert(0, './detector/')
from detect_events import main as detect_events

lemmatizer = Cube(verbose=True)
lemmatizer.load("es", tokenization=False, parsing=False)
...
```

This is the `docker-compose up` output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/luigi/__main__.py", line 20, in <module>
    luigi_run()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/luigi/cmdline.py", line 9, in luigi_run
    run_with_retcodes(argv)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/luigi/retcodes.py", line 70, in run_with_retcodes
    with luigi.cmdline_parser.CmdlineParser.global_instance(argv):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/luigi/cmdline_parser.py", line 52, in global_instance
    new_value = CmdlineParser(cmdline_args)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/luigi/cmdline_parser.py", line 64, in __init__
    self._attempt_load_module(known_args)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/luigi/cmdline_parser.py", line 142, in _attempt_load_module
    __import__(module)
  File "/tasks.py", line 13, in <module>
    from filter.filter import filter_spam
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'filter.filter'; 'filter' is not a package
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_sched.py", line 13, in <module>
    s.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/sched.py", line 154, in run
    action(*argument, **kwargs)
  File "my_sched.py", line 10, in cron
    output = subprocess.check_output(command.split(), shell= False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/bin/python', '-m', 'luigi', '--local-scheduler', '--module', 'tasks', 'Main']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
ERROR: Service 'orchestrator' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c python my_sched.py' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Finally, an overall vision of the working directory may help:

```
MABSED/
|_ docker-compose.yml
|_ ...
|_ orchestrator/
   |_ requirements.txt
   |_ tasks.py
   |_ my_sched.py
   |_ data/
   |_ detector/
   |_ filter/
      |_ filter.py
      |_ __init__.py
   |_ lemmatizer/
```

Finally just enphasize that the model works perfectly run on local, what gives the problem is when trying to convert it to Docker.

Comment: looks like your issue is this --> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'filter.filter'; 'filter' is not a package` can you try using a relative import?

Comment: A relative import would be 'from .filter.filter import filter_spam` ? @aws_apprentice

Comment: that is correct

Comment: It now returned this error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: Can you include how does the `my_sched.py` launch the `tasks.py` app? I think that's where the trouble lies.

Comment: @RichardNemeth Sure, I just edited the post adding it

Comment: Can you try setting in the orchestrator Dockerfile `ENV PYTHONPATH=/` before the `RUN` command? Perhaps even better to add it to the docker-compose instead.

Comment: Tried it both in Dockerfile and docker-compose, but still same output @RichardNemeth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigating through the running container I found out that folders were not being properly created and I was only copying its content instead of the folder itself, so the path `filter.filter` did not exist.

A possible solution is editing the service Dockerfile and copying everything in one single command instead of file by file, like this:

```
COPY . /
```

or if you don't want to copy all the files and just certain folders, you can solve this problem by specificating the folder on the destination path:

```
COPY filter/ filter/
```